# async await calling function node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have this function, that queries my database, and then calls `getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList` function:

```
var select = "select * from USERS WHERE ASSIGNED_TRAINER = ?"
mysqlconn.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Database connection failed: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }

    mysqlconn.query(select, [req.session.username], async function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            
            let numOfSessionsLeft = {
                numberOfSessionsLeftIs: 0
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList(req, res, rows[i], numOfSessionsLeft)
                rows[i]["NUM_OF_SESSIONS_PER_MONTH"] = (parseInt(rows[i]["NUM_OF_SESSIONS_PER_MONTH"]) - numOfSessionsLeft.numberOfSessionsLeftIs)
                console.log(numOfSessionsLeft)
            }
          

        }
        mysqlconn.end();

    })
})
```

and then inside the function `getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList`, I have this:

```
async function getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList(req, res, rows, numOfSessionsLeft) {

var getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList = "select * from SCHEDULE WHERE CLIENT_USERNAME = ? AND ASSIGNED_TRAINER = ?"
mysqlconn.connect(async function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Database connection failed: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }
        mysqlconn.query(getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList, [rows["USERNAME"], req.session.username], async function(err, sessionData) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                numOfSessionsLeft.numberOfSessionsLeftIs = 1;
                console.log(numOfSessionsLeft.numberOfSessionsLeftIs)

            }

        })

})

}
```

however, what is happening is that this line : `rows[i]["NUM_OF_SESSIONS_PER_MONTH"] = (parseInt(rows[i]["NUM_OF_SESSIONS_PER_MONTH"]) - numOfSessionsLeft.numberOfSessionsLeftIs)` is actually assigning `0` to `rows[i]["NUM_OF_SESSIONS_PER_MONTH"]` because that variable assignment is happening before the function call for `getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList` finishes. So it is happening out of sync. I am not sure how to fix this, i have run into issues with `async` `await` before, but nothing like this. would appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you produce [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger i tried my best to explain what the issue is and show what is happening. what else would you suggest adding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For loop is synchronous in nature and hence doesn't wait for your method `getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList` to return to continue the iteration.

The right way to do is:

1. Put your code inside an async block and use await() while calling `getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList` call.
2. Second, your function `getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList` should
   return a promise.

Sample:

```
async function functionA() {
    var select = "select * from USERS WHERE ASSIGNED_TRAINER = ?"
    mysqlconn.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Database connection failed: ' + err.stack);
            return;
        }
    
        mysqlconn.query(select, [req.session.username], async function(err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                
                let numOfSessionsLeft = {
                    numberOfSessionsLeftIs: 0
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    await getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList(req, res, rows[i], numOfSessionsLeft)
                    rows[i]["NUM_OF_SESSIONS_PER_MONTH"] = (parseInt(rows[i]["NUM_OF_SESSIONS_PER_MONTH"]) - numOfSessionsLeft.numberOfSessionsLeftIs)
                    console.log(numOfSessionsLeft)
                }
            }
            mysqlconn.end();
        })
    })
}
```

And your function getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList should look like:

```
async function getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList(req, res, rows, numOfSessionsLeft) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList = "select * from SCHEDULE WHERE CLIENT_USERNAME = ? AND ASSIGNED_TRAINER = ?"
        mysqlconn.connect(async function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Database connection failed: ' + err.stack);
                return reject(err);
            }
                mysqlconn.query(getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList, [rows["USERNAME"], req.session.username], async function(err, sessionData) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        return reject(err);
                    } else {
                        numOfSessionsLeft.numberOfSessionsLeftIs = 1;
                        console.log(numOfSessionsLeft.numberOfSessionsLeftIs)
                        return resolve();

                    }
                })

        })
    })

}
```

And then call `functionA()` with whatever params you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You call the function that includes async codes therefore getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList doesn't depend the codes above (starts with(rows[i]["NUM_OF and console) what you should do is

1. Make the function async by returning prom
2. execute it with await keyword

   ```
   async function trainerClientList(){

   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

               var getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList = "select * from SCHEDULE WHERE CLIENT_USERNAME = ? AND ASSIGNED_TRAINER = ?"
       mysqlconn.connect(async function(err) {
           if (err) {
               console.error('Database connection failed: ' + err.stack);
               resolve()
           }
               mysqlconn.query(getNumOfSessionForTrainerClientList, [rows["USERNAME"], req.session.username], async function(err, sessionData) {
                   if (err) {
                       console.log(err);
                   } else {
                       numOfSessionsLeft.numberOfSessionsLeftIs = 1;
                       console.log(numOfSessionsLeft.numberOfSessionsLeftIs)

                   }

               })

       })

       resolve()


   })
   ```

   }

   for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   await trainerClientList()
   rows[i]["NUM_OF_SESSIONS_PER_MONTH"] = (parseInt(rows[i]["NUM_OF_SESSIONS_PER_MONTH"]) - numOfSessionsLeft.numberOfSessionsLeftIs)
   console.log(numOfSessionsLeft)
   }

Comment: thanks for your answer. unfortunately it didn't seem to work. It provided me with the same outcome